# How to make column in serialised number even if one number is deleted

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-update, window-functions

I am having a table

```
FieldName | FieldValue | FieldOrder 
-------------------------------------
Srl       | value1     |  0
Data      | value2     |  0
Content   | value3     |  0
Srl       | val1       |  1
Data      | val2       |  1
Content   | val3       |  1
Srl       | vall1      |  2
Data      | vall2      |  2
Content   | vall3      |  2
Srl       | data1      |  3
Data      | data2      |  3
Content   | data3      |  3
```

If i am delete some rows that

```
Delete from CatogoryFieldValueMaster where FieldOrder = 1
//It will show result as
FieldName | FieldValue | FieldOrder 
-------------------------------------
Srl       | value1     |  0
Data      | value2     |  0
Content   | value3     |  0
Srl       | vall1      |  2
Data      | vall2      |  2
Content   | vall3      |  2
Srl       | data1      |  3
Data      | data2      |  3
Content   | data3      |  3
```

I need to update the table to reorder the FieldOrder column to show as 0,1,2,3....
What modifications do i need to do to get my table as

```
FieldName | FieldValue | FieldOrder 
-------------------------------------
Srl       | value1     |  0
Data      | value2     |  0
Content   | value3     |  0
Srl       | vall1      |  1
Data      | vall2      |  1
Content   | vall3      |  1
Srl       | data1      |  2
Data      | data2      |  2
Content   | data3      |  2
```

Please help me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I need to update the table to reorder the FieldOrder column to show as 0,1,2,3....

If you want to change the values, then use an updatable CTE as GMB suggests.  However, I would approach this using `dense_rank()` instead of `row_number()`:

```
with toupdate as (
      select cfvm.*,
             dense_rank() over (order by FieldOrder) - 1 as new_FieldOrder
      from CatogoryFieldValueMaster cfvm
     ) 
update toupdate
    set FieldOrder = new_FieldOrder
    where FieldOrder <> new_FieldOrder;
```

For the example you gave -- where an entire group of field orders are removed -- this and GMB's solution do the same thing.  If you remove one row, then they produce different results.  To me, this is more sensible, but you don't clarify what you really want to do.

Answer (score 2):

I would not recommend storing this derived information - because, as you are finding out, it is complicated to maintain it (potentially, you need to renumber the whole table after each change in the data).

Instead, you can compute it on the fly with `row_number()`  in a view:

```
create view CatogoryFieldValueMasterView as
select 
    FieldName,
    FieldValue,
    row_number() over(partition by FieldName order by FieldValue) - 1 FieldOrder
from CatogoryFieldValueMaster
```

That said, if you do want an `update` statement, here is an option using an updateable cte:

```
with cte as (
    select 
        FieldOrder,
        row_number() over(partition by FieldName order by FieldValue) - 1 FieldOrderNew
    from CatogoryFieldValueMaster
) 
update cte set FieldOrder = FieldOrderNew
```